# Redshift query to add column for date where maximum value has occurred so far

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table with columns `id`, `dt` and `amt`, with PK (`id`, `dt`) and ordered dates `dt` for each `id`. I want to create a column `curr_max_amt_dt`, which stores the date on which the maximum `amt` has occurred so far ignoring nulls, for each `id`. If the largest value so far occurs again, then we update with the latest date (like in `id = 2` below).

```
+----+------------+-------+-----------------+
| id |     dt     |  amt  | curr_max_amt_dt |
+----+------------+-------+-----------------+
|  1 | 2020-01-01 |     5 | 2020-01-01      |
|  1 | 2020-01-02 |    10 | 2020-01-02      |
|  1 | 2020-01-03 |  NULL | 2020-01-02      |
|  1 | 2020-01-04 |    15 | 2020-01-04      |
|  2 | 2020-01-01 |    20 | 2020-01-01      |
|  2 | 2020-01-02 |    20 | 2020-01-02      |
|  2 | 2020-01-03 |    15 | 2020-01-02      |
|  2 | 2020-01-04 |    10 | 2020-01-02      |
+----+------------+-------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't seem to find an existing solution but managed to come up with the following that works. It needs a CTE as Redshift doesn't allow nested window functions.

```
with t2 as (
    SELECT *
        , max(amt) over (partition by id order by dt asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as curr_max_amt
        , (case when amt = curr_max_amt then dt else NULL end) as curr_max_amt_dt_tmp
    FROM t
)
    SELECT id
        , amt
        , dt
        , last_value(curr_max_amt_dt_tmp) ignore nulls over (partition by id order by dt asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as curr_max_amt_dt 
    FROM t2
```

`curr_max_amt` is a temporary column to store the maximum amount so far. `curr_max_amt_dt_tmp` is another temporary column that keeps only dates that have the maximum amount so far, otherwise it is null. I then fill the empty values with the last non-null date to get `curr_max_amt_dt`.